# Count of total Numbers With 3 set Bits only in a range

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, binary-search

I recently come across a question , Question statement is like this :

For given value of  L and R, We have to find the count of number X, which have only three-set bits in it's binary representation such that "L ≤ X ≤ R".

Expected Time Complexity: O(log(63^3))

Expected Auxiliary Space: O(1)

Link - https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/akku-and-binary-numbers0902/0/

I have tried this solution but it is showing to optimize more , any suggestion how I can optimize it

```
 long long solve(long long l, long long r){
        long long count = 0,ctr=0;
        for(long long j=l; j<=r; j++){
            count = 0;
            for(int i=31; i>=0; i--)
            {    if(j & (1<<i))
                   count++; 
                if(count>3) break; // If counts more than 3 set bits then break it
            }
            if(count==3)
                ctr++;
        }
        return ctr;
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK `O(log(633))` and `O(1)` are exactly the same expression.

Comment: Remember that most of these do called code contests are actually "find the mathematical trick" contests. Given the constraints there will be a way of directly calculating the result rather than just testing every number

Comment: For numbers starting with a binary sequence with two ones and n remaining digits there are n possibilities, where the remaining one goes to. For numbers starting with a one (every positive integer number) and n remaining digits there are n * (n+1) / 2 possibilities, where the remaining two ones go. For a number 2^a + 2^b (with a > b) with two ones, the next higher number with that property is 2^a + 2^b + 2^b (for a > b + 1) or 2^a + 2^b + 2^b + 1 (else). You can calculate the position of the first one with floor(log(n)/log(2)), of the second one by repeating with n-2^[position of first one].

Comment: @Vorac Actually its Log(63^3)

Comment: Actually They have given some hints :  
We can precompute all the numbers having 3  bits set in range of 1 to 10^18 and store them.
For this we will apply three nested for loops on the bits that can be at max 63 bits as 2^63 >10^18.
Now, for each query we can use binary search to find the corresponding L and R and thus we have the
required count.

Comment: Probably they mean log(n^3)=log(n) with n the maximum numbers of binary digits

Comment: If you use n=number of binary digits, then the storage is not O(1) with the precomputation.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea behind the code is fairly simple. We generate binary numbers by taking set bits. In this question three set bits have been asked, so we will make three variables and run three while loops.

For example, numbers are asked --> 11 to 19

- we take i = 1 j = 2, k = 4 and start the loops. We make temp as OR of - i j and k.
  For example when representing in binary
- 1 = 0001
- 2 = 0010
- 4 = 0100

---

OR = 0111 --> 7 , Hence if the number is in the range [l,r] the count is increased.

Code by --> https://auth.geeksforgeeks.org/user/628826/practice/

```
long long solve(long long l, long long r){

    long long i = 1;
    long long cnt = 0;
    while (i < r)
    {
        long long j = i << 1;
        while (j < r)
        {
            long long k = j << 1;
            while (k < r)
            {
                long long tmp = i | j | k;
                //cout<<i<<" "<<j<<" "<<k<<" "<<tmp<<endl;
                if (l <= tmp && tmp <= r)
                    ++ cnt;
                k <<= 1;
            }
            j <<= 1;
        }
        i <<= 1;
    }
    
    return cnt;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this question without 3 loops, you can find pattern in bit-count.

Example :

```
                     //count of numbers having exactly x-setbits

    : 0 -> 00000000  //0-setBit = 1, 1-setBit = 0, 2-setBit = 0, 3-setBit = 0
--------------------------
2^0 : 1 -> 00000001  //0-setBit = 1, 1-setBit = 1, 2-setBit = 0, 3-setBit = 0
--------------------------
2^1 : 2 -> 00000010  
      3 -> 00000011  //0-setBit = 1, 1-setBit = 2, 2-setBit = 1, 3-setBit = 0
--------------------------
2^2 : 4 -> 00000100  
      5 -> 00000101
      6 -> 00000110
      7 -> 00000111  //0-setBit = 1, 1-setBit = 3, 2-setBit = 3, 3-setBit = 1
--------------------------
2^3 : 8 -> 00001000
      9 -> 00001001
     10 -> 00001010
     11 -> 00001011
     12 -> 00001100
     13 -> 00001101
     14 -> 00001110
     15 -> 00001111  //0-setBit = 1, 1-setBit = 4, 2-setBit = 6, 3-setBit = 4
--------------------------
2^n : .....
```

Now notice that each new container (enclosed with "-----") contains all the previous containers in sequence with 1 added in front of them.

Example :

1. 2^2 container is made up of 0, 2^0, 2^1 containers with 1 added at third bit.
2. 2^3 container is made up of 0, 2^0, 2^1, 2^2 containers with 1 added at fourth bit

Using this observation we notice that **"every exactly x-setbits count = x-setbits + (x-1)-setbits(of prev container)"** as current container is made up of prev container+1

Since we are only required to find exactly 3-setbits count we can further optimize this.

Notice:

1. exactly 0-setbit count is **always 1**
2. exactly 1-setbit count is **n for containers less than 2^n if n >= 1 else 0** (sum of 1)
3. exactly 2-setbit count is **n(n-1)/2 for containers less than 2^n if n >= 2 else 0** (sum of n)
4. exactly 3-setbit count is **n(n-1)(n-2)/6 for containers less than 2^n if n >= 3 else 0** (sum of sum of n)

**=> we can compute required values of all containers less than 2^n in O(1).**

Now, given problem can be broken down as:

**Count of exactly 3-setbit in range [L,R] == Count in range [0,R] - Count in range [0,L-1]**

Code:

```cpp
long long compute(long long n,long long k){
    switch(k){
        case 1 : return n < 1 ? 0 : n;
        case 2 : return n < 2 ? 0 : n*(n-1)/2;
        case 3 : return n < 3 ? 0 : n*(n-1)*(n-2)/6;
    }
    return -1;
}

long long cal(long long val,long long k){
    if(k == 0)return 1;
    if(val == 0)return 0;
    long long n = log2(val);

    long long res = compute(n,k) + cal(val-(1LL<<n),k-1);
    return res;
}


long long solve(long long l, long long r){
    return cal(r,3) - cal(l-1,3);
}
```

Complexity:

- Time Complexity: O(log(n))
- Space Complexity: O(1)

This solution is working for the link which is provided in the question